# .htaccess 301 redirect only for google bot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am essentialy trying to cloak Google certain pages on my site to another. Reason being is i am using this site for paid traffic but i wish to send the SEO traffic elsewhere (via a 301 redirection) as the conversions will be better.

Anyway here is the htaccess i have written so far but i dont know how to add multiple pages.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://www.currentsite.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://www.currentsite.com/page1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/page1 [L,R=301]
```

I assume you can see what i am trying to achieve, redirecting page1 to page1 etc.

Thanks

Morgan

Comment: You need `robots.txt`, not `.htaccess`

Comment: you cannot do a 301 redirection via robots.txt ?

Answer (score 4):

`RewriteCond` work only with the first `RewriteRule` just after. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://www.currentsite.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3|etc)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a `robots.txt` in your main folder with this content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page_to_hide1
Disallow: /page_to_hide2
Disallow: /page_to_hide3
```

Find more information here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en   http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: This is not 301 redirecting the pages, this is simply not indexing certain pages.

Comment: This is what `robots.txt` is made for - to tell google (for eample) that you don't want certain pages indexed.

Comment: But i want to redirect the certain pages. I never said anything about not indexing them